# How do I check if both of two variables exists in Python?

Tags: python

I want to write a statement like this javascript in Python:

`if (variable1 && variable2) {
    // do something only if both variables exist
}`

I'm trying:

`if not (variable1 and variable2) is None:
    # do something only if both variables exist`

but it isn't working...when I debug, variable 2 is not defined but the function still tries to run. What's going wrong?

Comment: Why would these variables ever not exist?

Comment: What do you mean by not defined?

Comment: They are variables sometimes created in prior if statements, and in my case variable two was passed over and not defined. I'm getting this error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'variable2' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
try:
    variable1
    variable2
except NameError:
    # Not there
else:
    # They exist
```

This is a pretty rare thing to want to do. Make sure it's actually a good idea before you do it.

Note that a variable being set to `None` is different from it not existing. If you want to check whether the variables are `None`, you're just messing up the boolean logic syntax:

```
if variable1 is not None and variable2 is not None:
    do_whatever()
```

This can be simplified if the not-`None` values are guaranteed to be considered true in a boolean context. For example, if `variable1` and `variable2` are the results of `re.search` calls, they'll either be match objects or `None`, and you can use:

```
if variable1 and variable2:
    do_whatever()
```

Comment: +1. However this may have some side effects when variable1 shapes like `foo.bar` and there's a getter property for member `bar` in `class foo`

Comment: @starrify: It won't even work in that case, considering `AttributeError`s aren't `NameError`s.

Comment: I didn't mean that. Could you please have a look at this code example? https://gist.github.com/starrify/9183346

Comment: @starrify: I see what you mean, but now try that with an `f` that doesn't even have a `bar` attribute. `f=None`, for example.

Comment: Oh I see your point. Thank you. :) I was wring my own answer when I saw your answer came up, and what's unlucky is that I'm using exactly the same method as yours. However now I think it's better to manually seek the identifier in `locals()` XD

Comment: @starrify: `locals` runs into weird edge cases with closure variables, though.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the samething in Python.

```
if variable1 and variable2:
    ...
```

But this means that, both the variables have [Truthy values](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in them.

**Note:** Using a variable which hasn't been assigned a value, is an error in Python.

If you really want to check if the variables are defined already, you can use this hack but I won't recommend this

```
if (variable1 in locals() and variable2 in locals()):
   ...
```

If there are more variables you want to check,

```
if all(var in locals() for var in (variable1, variable2, variable3)):
```

Answer (score 3):

You connect the two variables by a boolean operator. What you actually want is to `and` the outcome of the two comparisons.

```
if variable1=!None and variable2=!None:
    # do something
```

Apart from that a non-existing variable is not None but not existing.
If you want to check whether a variable exists, check if it is defined in the `globals()` or `locals()`:

```
if "variable1" in locals() and "variable2" in locals():
    # do something
```

Note that the variables are quoted here, since you do not want to evaluate them!